# Flickering / tearing when moving divs via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbvEA/) is a sample that caused the flickering / tearing. On the 2nd moon and its orbit of the 3rd planet.

The code working in FF, but not in jsfiddle. It works in jsfiddle and chrome just fine. In IE it works with jsfiddle, but looks odd for the lack of css3 support. All of them have the flicker / tearing issue though. Its like the webpage isn't updated on the vsync or some such thing.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: I've got nothing on the tearing issue except to say that I don't see it (Firefox 4), but your code could be vastly improved by caching your `$(this)`, passing a single object to `css` (thus calling it only once) instead of calling each time for every property, don't use custom attributes but rather `data-*` attributes and jQuery's `data` function. Also, no need to use `parseFloat` with `outerWidth` since that already returns all numbers, and you can try using `position` instead of CSS. And finally, why are you using a 2 year old version of jQuery? Use 1.5.1!

Comment: @Yi Jiang - sorry, picked the wrong jQuery verion from the list. I am using 1.5.1 (that fixes it not working in FF as well). I'll try the changes you're suggesting

Comment: Is this the Kerbal System?